# On set of critical values of differentiable function

Tags: measure-theory

Given any closed subset $C$ of $[0,1]$ show that it is the set of critical values of some differentibale function from $R \rightarrow R$.

Comment: Off the top of my head: $[0,1]\setminus C$ is an at most countable union of disjoint open intervals $I_k$ so if we take bump functions $1\ge f_k>0$ on $I_k$ and $0$ everywhere else, then $f=\sum \frac{f_k}{2^{k}}$ is one such function.